# Run Java program at certain periods, hosted online?

Tags: java

I'm fairly new to running programs from servers.

I have a program built in Java. I want to run that program every few minutes and update the new results. I can do this from my computer but I have to leave it on, with internet, etc...

I figured I could host this somewhere and have it do this for me, and then send me JSON results. What is the design pattern to do this?

I have built apis using php but never Java. Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would depend entirely on the host.

Any cloud server ([Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/), [Rackspace](http://www.rackspace.com/cloud/servers/overview_b/), [GoGrid](https://www.gogrid.com/products/cloud-hosting)) where you can provision your own virtual server would be perfect for this.  Since you can SSH or Remote in, you can setup a cron job or NT Scheduler job to run your Java program.

Also, services like [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) (and I believe Windows Azure) let you provision worker instances, which can do this sort of job.  For Heroku, check out [background workers](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/background-jobs-queueing).

Comment: Some of these (e.g. Amazon) have a free tier, which may be all that the OP needs